# Move watermark under beamer palette

Tags: beamer, watermark

I add a watermark to all frame in beamer presentation but I have this problem:
[image]
I would like the watermark when it overlaps with the palette to go under so that it does not appear.
How could I do to get a result like in the picture?
[image]

This is the code that I wrote:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

% === Change default option ===

    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \definecolor{green}{HTML}{00753B}

    \definecolor{mybackground}{HTML}{82CAFA}
    \definecolor{myforeground}{HTML}{0000A0}

    \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=green, bg=green}
    \setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white, bg=green}
    \setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=white, bg=gray!50!white}

    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black, bg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black, bg=white}

    \setbeamertemplate{headline}
    {
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{subsection in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

    \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
    \setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=green}
    \setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=green}
    \setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=green}

    \setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=green,fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection number projected}{bg=green,fg=white}

    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{green}$\bullet$}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{orange}$\blacktriangleright$}
% ==============================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, physics, booktabs, tikz, graphicx}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\title{\bfseries{High Performance network for HPC}}
\author[Riccardo Nigrelli]{Riccardo Nigrelli}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=gray,opacity=0.2]\node{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{images/logo.pdf}};}
\newwatermark*[
    allpages,
    angle=30,
    scale=3,
    xpos=45,
    ypos=30
]{\usebox\mybox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage 
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newwatermark*` (rather than `\newwatermark`) puts the watermark on the foreground. However, just dropping the `*` does not solve the problem because you have a page background, below which it will get hidden.

Comment: Message from samcarter: apart from dropping the `*` in `\newwatermark*` add `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}` to the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use external packages, you could simply add your watermark to the `background canvas` template:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

% === Change default option ===


    \definecolor{green}{HTML}{00753B}

    \definecolor{mybackground}{HTML}{82CAFA}
    \definecolor{myforeground}{HTML}{0000A0}

    \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=green, bg=green}
    \setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white, bg=green}
    \setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=white, bg=gray!50!white}

    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black, bg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black, bg=white}

    \setbeamertemplate{headline}
    {
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{subsection in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        }%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

    \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
    \setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=green}
    \setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=green}
    \setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=green}

    \setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=green,fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection number projected}{bg=green,fg=white}

    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{green}$\bullet$}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{orange}$\blacktriangleright$}
% ==============================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, physics, booktabs, tikz, graphicx}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\title{\bfseries{High Performance network for HPC}}
\author[Riccardo Nigrelli]{Riccardo Nigrelli}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\tikz[color=gray,opacity=0.2]\node{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage 
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```